# custom form:errors for spring mvc validation

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, custom-error-pages

I am using Spring 3 MVC and simply I want to display error messages at **a particular order**.

The logic below I added is working fine. However I would like to add a **if statement** to check whether there is a such error or not. In case an error, I would to add **"tr"** block

```
<table cellpadding="0" >
      <c:forEach items="accountBean.nameSurname,accountBean.creditCart,accountBean.cvc" var="err" >
      <%--check error for controlling--%>                
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><div class="attention"></div></td>
        <td valign="middle" align="left"><form:errors path="${err}"></form:errors> </td>
      </tr>
      </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about such a solution?

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="center">
  <c:forEach items="nameSurname,creditCart,cvc,monthAndYear" var="err" >
  <spring:bind path="accountBean.${err}" >
  <c:if test="${status.error}">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><div class="attention"></div></td>
    <td valign="middle" align="left">${status.errorMessage}</td>
  </tr>
  </c:if>
  </spring:bind>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```